# How to hide a combo box in an externally controlled application

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have an application A (.NET/WPF), which controls application B via WinAPI calls.

According to the requirements, application A must always be the topmost window. This means that

- if the window of application A is located at the same position as the window of application B,
- then the window of application A should be visible, and
- the window of application B must not be visible.

This requirement is satisfied in all cases except one. When application A programmatically selects an element from a combo box in application B, that combo box becomes visible for a moment. After an element is selected, it is hidden again.

But the combo box being visible (even for a few moments) is a violation of the requirements.

How can I make sure that the window of appliation A is **always** the topmost window (even during selection of a combo box item) ?

Note: Application A takes back focus (activates itself) every 200 milliseconds. I tried to reduce that interval to 100 milliseconds, but it didn't help.

**Update 1:** The combo box item is selected using following WinAPI calls.

```
SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, WPARAM(true), 0);

ItemIndex := SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, CB_FINDSTRING, -1, integer(@MyValue[1]));

OutputDebugString(PChar('ItemIndex: ' + IntToStr(ItemIndex)));


SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, ItemIndex, 0);
SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, CN_COMMAND, MakeWParam(0, CBN_SELCHANGE), 0);


SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, -1);
SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, -1);
```

Comment: First recommendation would be to give B a decent remote interface, but i guess you just can't change B. Would it be possible to (temporarily) move B to a screen location outside the visible area, let's say x=-1000?

Comment: I proposed this solution (moving and/or minimizing the window), but it was rejected by the customer.

Comment: Regarding *decent remote interface*: No, I can't do that because the application doesn't have an automation layer and the developers are unlikely to provide it. This is the very reason why the interaction is made via GUI.

Comment: That's a dirty way. How are you selecting the item in that combo box ? It sounds strange that sending `CB_SETCURSEL` would bring the combo box' parent window to top (not talking about combo box itself, what would have be some sort of magic). Are you sure you're not bringing that parent window to top during that item selection ? How are you controlling that application B (the code would explain it best) ? What is the application B written in ?

Comment: How are you selecting the item that combo box: I select the combo box item using WinAPI calls listed in *Update 1*.

Comment: How are you controlling that application B? - I do it using a DLL, which is injected into the address space of application B.

Comment: What is the application B written in ? - Delphi 2009

Comment: Remove the first and last two lines and you'll be fine. There's no need to show a combo list (which is probably the cause of your problem) and you don't need to simulate a click (even on a nonsense position).

Comment: No, this doesn't work (I just tried to comment out `SendMessage(Self.SelectFlightComboBox, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, WPARAM(true), 0);`, `SendMessage(Self.SelectFlightComboBox, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, -1)` and `SendMessage(Self.SelectFlightComboBox, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, -1)`).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to show a drop down list for a *background* combo box item selection, so remove the first line with the [`CB_SHOWDROPDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message sending (what might be a cause of your problem) and remove also the last two lines, where you're simulating left mouse button click (on a nonsense position, anyway), there's no reason to do so at all.

So, to select an item in combo box by a found text, it's enough to use the following pseudo-code (written in Delphi and slightly modified from your original version, since you should definitely check the results of the messages you send):

```
ItemIndex := SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, CB_FINDSTRING, -1, LPARAM(@MyValue[1]));
if ItemIndex <> CB_ERR then
  if SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, CB_SETCURSEL, ItemIndex, 0) <> CB_ERR then
    SendMessage(Self.MyFlightComboBox, CN_COMMAND, MakeWParam(0, CBN_SELCHANGE), 0);
```

Comment: See my comment to your comment to the question. Unfortunately, it isn't possible to find out the index of the item without showing the dropdown list (or, at least, commenting out the first line leads to item index being -1).

Comment: If I comment out the mouse button click lines, the selection is started, but not finalized (dropdown list is shown, the item selected, but it is not closed).

Comment: That's what wouldn't surprise me, but it is and always was enough to find the item by `CB_FINDSTRING` without *hacks* you're showing.

Comment: Here you have a [`simple proof`](http://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2F13172282) of it (both applications are written in Delphi 2009 though, but it doesn't matter in which language is the controller written when you're sending WinAPI messages).

Comment: Sorry, but this (finding out the index of the combo box item without showing the list) doesn't work, neither with pure WinAPI calls in Delphi, nor MS UI Automation in C# (tried both). Possible reason: Application A activates itself (sets focus to itself) every 200 milliseonds.